# Does boost::weak_ptr throw exceptions?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I'm reading the `Boost` documentation for `weak_ptr` [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) and in the beginning it says:

> When the last shared_ptr to the object goes away and the object is
>   deleted, the attempt to obtain a shared_ptr from the weak_ptr
>   instances that refer to the deleted object will fail: the constructor
>   will throw an exception of type boost::bad_weak_ptr, and
>   weak_ptr::lock will return an empty shared_ptr.

Everything clear so far, however, 2 lines later it says:

> weak_ptr operations never throw exceptions.

What does each statement refer to?

Comment: It is `shared_ptr` which throws `bad_weak_ptr` (when you try construct it from `weak_ptr`). There is no contradiction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `weak_ptr` class **never throws** on any operation, internally, what happens when you call `lock()` is that it catches the exception thrown by the *constructor* of the `shared_ptr` (`bad_weak_ptr`) and then returns you an empty `shared_ptr`. Have a look at the source of the `lock()` function for yourself to confirm.

Comment: `weak_ptr::lock` hasn't been catching exceptions since version 1.36, it now use another overload of the `shared_ptr` constructor which doesn't throw.

Answer (score 2):

Constructing a `shared_ptr` from a `weak_ptr` may throw an `bad_weak_ptr` exception. (Use `weak_ptr::lock` instead, if you want to be able to test for this.)

Any operations on a `weak_ptr` object itself will not throw.

Answer (score 1):

It means that if you construct a shared_ptr (`template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(weak_ptr<Y> const & r);` ) from a weak_ptr when the shared instance referenced by the weak_ptr is gone, it will throw an exception.

You have two ways to obtain shared_ptr from weak_ptr :

- shared_ptr constructor, it will throw if the instance referenced by the weak_ptr is gone
- `shared_ptr<T> weak_ptr<T>::lock() const;` it will return an empty instance of shared_ptr if the instance referenced by the weak_ptr is gone.